# How to add a custom field with fb:request-form tag

Tags: facebook, fbml

I need to add a custom field with the fb:request-form tag in facebook. ie:- I need the user enter some value in a text box and then select his/her facebook friends and when the user send the invitation with the selected uid's i need to process the value that the user entered in the text box.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do something like this:

```
<fb:request-form action="URL_TO_POST_TO" method="POST">
  <fb:multi-friend-selector with="all" needed="params" />
  <input name="posted" value="true" type="hidden" />
  <input name="test" type="text" />
</fb:request-form>
```

In URL_TO_POST_TO you should receive these POST params too, in addition to the ones that FB adds after the request/invitation is sent.